# Facebook Like Box not loading on Ember app

Tags: javascript, facebook, ember.js, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get the like box to work inside our ember app, in a template called `about`. The problem is that if I enter the ember app from another route (instead of `about` route), then navigate to the `about` route with `link-to` helpers, then the like box is not rendered. Instead, if I enter/refresh the `about` route directly, it renders just fine. Any ideas on how to make it render even if somebody navigates to that route from another route ?

**templates/about.hbs:**

```
...
<div class = "fb-like-box" data-href = "https://www.facebook.com/app-link" data-width = "250"
                 data-height = "313" data-colorscheme = "light" data-show-faces = "true" data-header = "false"
                 data-stream = "false" data-show-border = "true"></div>
...
```

**views/application.js:**

```
export default Ember.View.extend({

  facebook_app_id: config.APP.facebook_app_id,

  initLibs: function ()
            {
              // initialize Facebook SDK
              var facebook_id = this.facebook_app_id;
              window.fbAsyncInit = function ()
              {
                FB.init({
                  appId:   facebook_id,
                  xfbml:   true,
                  version: 'v2.1'
                });
              };
              (function (d, s, id)
              {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id))
                {
                  return;
                }
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
              }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
            }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the Facebook JS SDK “goes through” your document once when it is initialized, and looks for elements to parse and convert into FB social plugins. But if you only load and add those elements later, that of course doesn’t work.

But the SDk offers a method to re-parse the document for such elements, [FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) – so call that after your new elements are added to the DOM. (You can either let it look through the whole document again, or pass in a reference to a specific DOM element, so that it will only evaluate a “sub-tree” of the document, for better performance.)

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation and the fb parse method, really helped. It didn't really work when parsing a single DOM element but whatever, it gets the job done, as the respective template is quite small.

Comment: Did you pass a “pure” reference to a DOM element? If it is still wrapped in some library code, that won’t work I would assume.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that your script is manipulating the `DOM` outside of Ember. This will make it impossible for ember to track the state of the DOM and manipulate it.

Your logic assumes that the script tag will be first, which you have no guarantee of since Ember is creating and removing script tags.

Rather than creating the element through code, you can simply include the script tag directly.

Put this in `app/index.html`:

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

Remove your logic from application.js and implement the following in `views/about.js`:

```
export default Ember.View.extend({

    facebook_app_id: config.APP.facebook_app_id,

    didInsertElement : function(){
        this._super();
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function(){
              // initialize Facebook SDK
              var facebook_id = this.facebook_app_id;
              window.fbAsyncInit = function ()
              {
                FB.init({
                  appId:   facebook_id,
                  xfbml:   true,
                  version: 'v2.1'
                });
              };                    
        });
    }
});
```

You can also extract this functionality into a component, since it seems like a perfect candidate.

Comment: What behavior are you experiencing, the same as you describe initially? Have you confirmed that sdk.js has loaded?

Comment: Same behaviour. Yes, sdk.js has loaded.

Comment: Just realized that you have your logic in `views\application.js` - it needs to be in `views\about.js`.

Comment: Let me know if that works, otherwise there is another tweak you can make.

Comment: Tried it in about.js too before asking the question, same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70785/discussion-between-andrew-and-oren).